# How to restrict access to an appengine application only to the owners and developers?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an application developed and deployed on Google App Engine, and i want to make some integration test so is there a way to let the application (MyappId.appspot.com) only visible by me (owner) and others that were added as developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set to the configuration of the application to allow only admin users. An example for Python is presented to the [App Engine documentation for Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Requiring_login_or_administrator_status) .

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays you can use Google Identity Aware Proxy https://cloud.google.com/iap

Answer (score 1):

From the [App Engine documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication):

> If the constraint specifies a user role of admin, then only registered
>   developers of the application can access the URL. The admin role makes
>   it easy to build administrator-only sections of your site.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: how about an application wich developped with python ?

Answer (score 1):

@Andrei Volgin

Thanks for the link: i have read the documentation about App Engine python apps and see that we can just add `login: admin` to our yaml file like this:

```
- url: /.*
  script: handler.application
  secure: always
  login: admin
```

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_About_app_yaml)